# Where do you put your dependencies?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection

If I use the dependency injection pattern to remove dependencies they end up some where else.

For example, Snippet 1, or what I call Object Maker.

I mean you have to instantiate your objects somewhere...so when you move dependency out of one object, you end up  putting it another one.

I see that this consolidates all my dependencies into one object.  Is that the point, to reduce your dependencies so that they all reside in a single ( as close to as possible ) location?

**Snippet 1 - Object Maker**

```
<?php

class ObjectMaker
{
    public function makeSignUp()
    {
        $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        $TextObject = new Text();
        $MessageObject = new Message();

        $SignUpObject = new ControlSignUp();        
        $SignUpObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $SignUpObject;
    }
    public function makeSignIn()
    {
        $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        $TextObject = new Text();
        $MessageObject = new Message();

        $SignInObject = new ControlSignIn();
        $SignInObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $SignInObject;
    }
    public function makeTweet( $DatabaseObject = NULL, $TextObject = NULL, $MessageObject = NULL )
    {
        if( $DatabaseObject == 'small' )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        }
        else if( $DatabaseObject == NULL )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
            $TextObject = new Text();
            $MessageObject = new Message();
        }
        $TweetObject = new ControlTweet();        
        $TweetObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject, $TextObject, $MessageObject);
        return $TweetObject;
    }
    public function makeBookmark( $DatabaseObject = NULL, $TextObject = NULL, $MessageObject = NULL )
    {
        if( $DatabaseObject == 'small' )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
        }
        else if( $DatabaseObject == NULL )
        {
            $DatabaseObject = new Database();
            $TextObject = new Text();
            $MessageObject = new Message();
        }

        $BookmarkObject = new ControlBookmark();        
        $BookmarkObject->setObjects($DatabaseObject,$TextObject,$MessageObject);
        return $BookmarkObject;
    }
}
```

Comment: it's really weird that how you phrase a question determines the answer you get.

Comment: This post has the opposite tone - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156341/are-there-any-pros-to-using-the-dependency-injection-pattern-if-you-do-not-run-u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it has nothing to do with consolidating your dependencies.  It has everything to do with making objects more testable.

Yes, a side-effect is that your dependencies tend to show up somewhere else, but the point is that the dependencies are not in the object you are testing.

If you don't create the dependencies in the target object, then you can instantiate test (or fake or mock) objects to feed into your target object.  If the object created its own dependencies, then that would not be possible.

Think of it like this.  Let's say you have a Car object.  If the car created the driver, then there would be no way for other drivers to drive it.  It could only be an All Foo Car, because you have a hard coded creation of the driver.

Now, let's say we develop a robot to test the car on a specially designed race track.  Again, we could not put the robot in the driver seat, because you would be hard coded there.

Of course testability is just one benefit of dependency injection, the forced decoupling of dependencies means that you have to write more modular code.  If you're using a dependency injection framework (Crafty, or similar) then you can make dependencies auto-instantiate themselves as needed, which has lots of benefits, but that tends to be more of a benefit with stronger typed languages.

Comment: @TheAllFoo - Dependencies must exist somewhere, otherwise they're not dependencies.  They don't instantiate themselves (despite what I said above, something is still creating them)

Comment: I put all mine in a file called ObjectMaker just posted it ( above ), I need to abstract out the common elements still.

Answer (score 2):

I, personally, would rather instantiate the objects wherever it makes sense to instantiate them, and to document dependencies well in a special documentation file.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask yourself, "does this belong together?"

If something is "a part of" your object, then probably "yes".  If something is "a property of", then yes.

[Keep it Simple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K.I.S.S) :)

The best guideline I can offer?  From the PHP manual:

> http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php
>
> A PHP Class can be used for several things, but at the most basic
>   level, you'll use classes to "organize and deal with like-minded
>   data".

PS:
Create an object where you first need it.

PPS:
"consolidate all my dependencies into one object" ... if the objects you're bunching together don't necessarily have anything directly to do with each other ... is probably the WORST thing you could do.  IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

> Is that the point, to reduce your dependencies so that they all reside in a single (as close to as possible) location?

I think that's basically it, yes.  The idea is to make the components of an application loosely coupled.  That means you can more easily re-use components, interchange them, and test against them.  If you have a simple application, of course it works perfectly well to instantiate objects where they're needed.  But as it grows more complex, with multiple nested dependencies, your code can become tightly-coupled, which means difficult to maintain, adapt, and test.

Comment: it is dependent upon the complexity of your code...I got up to about 1200 lines before I started using it.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection%20Wikipedia)

> In conventional software development the dependent object decides for itself what concrete classes it will use. In the dependency injection pattern, this decision is delegated to the "injector" which can choose to substitute different concrete class implementations of a dependency contract interface at run-time rather than at compile time.

DI results in certain classes that have less coupling to **unstable classes**. The instances that are injected are usually implementations of an interface. OCP tells that changes in implementations should not require modifying closed classes that depend on them.

**tl;dr** class A that depends only on implementations of interface I that are *injected* to it is more cohesive (has less responsibilities). Some other class gets stuck with the responsibility of selecting, instantiating, etc., but that class is also more cohesive.