# Where do you set up dependencies on or related to a php file for a heroku facebook application in php?

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, database-connection

I have heard of something called pear or phing to set up dependencies that I think is some sort of php module. Essentially I want to make use of Heroku's 5mb of postgresql database storage, and I'm following the node.js tutorial for setting up a postgresql database.

I don't know about makefiles in php, but I gather that php probably has a file like in c++ that requires dependencies, but I'm not sure how to write dependencies in that regard. I noticed that there are pretty much little to no info about setting up a postgres db for php in facebook anywhere. I have a feeling I'm supposed to create dependencies within a php file itself, from : [Where do you put your dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157824/where-do-you-put-your-dependencies)